# ¿El parametro url de fetch(), puede ser un archivo .json en local, o solo una api que esté en internet?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Verán, mi programa es solo mostrar los datos de mi base de datos desde xampp en formato .json para trabajar con fetch(), y resulta bien.

Pero cuando, en lugar de llamar mi archivo llamado json.php (donde se genera mi texto en .json) llamo a json.json (que escribí toda la bd a mano para verificar como funcionaba) me suelta este error: 
**"Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sistemas2/Desktop/Portafolio/practicando-JSON/json.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."** y no sé a que se deba. Muchas gracias.

Este es el código.

```
    <!--HTML--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Practicando</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Buscar" id="buscar"><br>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>PAIS</th>
        <th>EDAD</th>
        <th>OCUPACIÓN</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="contenido">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el script

```
var busqueda = document.getElementById("buscar");
busqueda.addEventListener('click', obtenerDatos);

function obtenerDatos(){
    // fetch('json.php') --- Este fetch si lo lee bien que es cuando estoy corriendo xampp
    fetch('json.json')
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( datos => {
        pintarTabla(datos)
    });
}
function pintarTabla(datos){
    contenido.innerHTML = "";
    for (let valor of datos){
        contenido.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${valor.id}</td>
                <td>${valor.nombre}</td>
                <td>${valor.pais}</td>
                <td>${valor.edad}</td>
                <td>${valor.ocupacion}</td>
            <tr>
        `
    }

}
```

Mi php de la conexión cuando corro xampp y cuando hago la función getAll() para hacer que mi url json.php sea de tipo .json.

```
<?php
class conexion {
    public static function conn(){
        $link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","personas");
        $link->set_charset("utf8");
        return $link;
    }
}
class personas{
    private $db;
    private $lista;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->db=conexion::conn();
            $this->lista=array();
        }
        public function traerTabla(){
            $tabla=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM personas");
            while($filas=$tabla->fetch_assoc()){
                $this->lista[]=$filas;
            }
            return $this->lista;
        }
        public function obtenerDatos(){
            $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM personas");

            return $query;
        }
        public function getAll(){
            $datosPersonas = new personas();
            $datos = array();
            $res = $datosPersonas->obtenerDatos();
            if ($res){
                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                    $item = array(
                        'id' => $row['id_Personas'],
                        'nombre' => $row['Nombre'],
                        'pais' => $row['Pais'],
                        'edad' => $row['Edad'],
                        'ocupacion' => $row['Ocupación']
                    );
                    array_push($datos, $item);
                }
                echo json_encode($datos);
            }else{
                echo json_encode(array('mensaje' => 'No hay elementos registrados'));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

El archivo que solo genera el texto en .json (json.php)

```
<?php
include_once 'conexion.php';

$api = new personas();

$api->getAll();
?>
```

Este es mi archivo **json.json** que en el fetch() del script quiero leer pero al momento de correr el programa me sale el error que mencione al principio.

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "nombre":"Antonio",
        "pais":"Mexico",
        "edad":"26",
        "ocupacion":"Estudiante"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "nombre":"Juan",
        "pais":"Ecuador",
        "edad":"30",
        "ocupacion":"Ingeniero en sistemas"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "nombre":"Ximena",
        "pais":"Argentina",
        "edad":"20",
        "ocupacion":"Disenadora grafica"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "nombre":"Alberto",
        "pais":"Chile",
        "edad":"29",
        "ocupacion":"Gerente de operaciones"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "nombre":"Marcela",
        "pais":"Mexico",
        "edad":"24",
        "ocupacion":"Consultora"
    },
    {
        "id":"6",
        "nombre":"Carmen",
        "pais":"Chile",
        "edad":"27",
        "ocupacion":"Abogada"
    },
    {
        "id":"7",
        "nombre":"Salvador",
        "pais":"Argentina",
        "edad":"49",
        "ocupacion":"Analista de datos"
    },
    {
        "id":"8",
        "nombre":"Marcelo",
        "pais":"Mexico",
        "edad":"39",
        "ocupacion":"Desarrollador de software"
    },
    {
        "id":"9",
        "nombre":"Georgina",
        "pais":"Ecuador",
        "edad":"31",
        "ocupacion":"Recepcionista"
    },
    {
        "id":"10",
        "nombre":"Gilberto",
        "pais":"Chile",
        "edad":"23",
        "ocupacion":"Calidad"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando fetch es simple.

```js
fetch("./archivo.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: No, me sigue saliendo ese error **"Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sistemas2/Desktop/Portafolio/practicando-JSON/json.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."**

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero esto pasa cuando tu html no esta en un servicio http o https, es decir, tiene que estar en un servidor con esos protocolos, de tal forma que localmente puedes correrlo con un servicio como Xampp o NodeJS

Comment: Puedes probar esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/517544/272521