# Cargar un JSON en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Tengo un que cargar un archivo con javascript.

El caso es que pongo la ruta y me da este error:

> load.js:8 Fetch API cannot load
> file:///E:/proyectos/proyectos%20javascript/workshop/entrega/json/numero2.json.
> URL scheme "file" is not supported.

Este es el código de javascript

```javascript
function getData(){
    fetch('../entrega/json/numero2.json')
        .then(res=>res.json)
        .then(datos=>{
            console.log(datos);
        })
}
```

Y esta es la estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado con [`JSON.parse(res.json)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: Cuál es el nombre archivo JS desde el cual quieres obtener el archivo JSON?

Comment: El archivo se llama load.js

Comment: Puedes poner en dónde está ese archivo? En tu captura de pantalla no lo veo. Siento que el problema es que no estás poniendo el path al archivo JSON de forma correcta.

Comment: Asumiendo que tu archivo esté en la carpeta `js`, la forma correcta de cargarlo sería: `./../json/número.JSON`. Lo que tienes en tu código indica que de la carpeta `js` suba un nivel, y en dicha carpeta padre busque `entrega`. Dicha carpeta no existe. De existir deberías tener una carpeta entrega dentro de la carpeta entrega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el error, parece que estas corriendo tu JS directamente desde tu computadora (`file:///E:/proyecto/...`). Lo mejor es correr un webserver localmente y acceder a tu proyecto usando HTTP y localhost (`http://localhost:3000` por ejemplo).

Hay varios paquetes NPM que te permiten hacerlo, por ejemplo, puedes probar:

```sh
npm install -g serve
```

Y luego, desde el directorio donde esta tu proyecto (`E:/proyectos/proyectos%20javascript/workshop/`), ejecutas:

```sh
serve
```

Te va a aparecer un mensaje como el siguiente, donde te dice como acceder desde tu browser a tu proyecto por HTTP.

```
   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                  │
   │   Serving!                                       │
   │                                                  │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:60227     │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://10.1.1.87:60227     │
   │                                                  │
   │   This port was picked because 5000 is in use.   │
   │                                                  │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!             │
   │                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```